# excel not summing time properly

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I would like to know how I can go about formatting a time so that it shows on the spreadsheet as 10hr12min not as 10:12, preferably as vba. becaue a change could take 24 hours and it come up as 00:00 and when i sum two times like this it should be 48 hours and 0 minutes not just 00:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Greg, the format to display correctly the sum of time data properly is with `[h]` instead of `h`, in your case `[h]"hr"mm"min"`

In VBA:

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "[h]""hr""mm""min"""
```

Answer (score 1):

Try custom formatting the cell to:  [h]:mm

This will keep just the hours and minutes in the cell instead of the actual time.  The sum will then work appropriately.

Credit to:  [Mr Excel form archives](http://www.mrexcel.com/archive/Formatting/15278.html)

Comment: Then the proper answer should be `[h]"hr"mm"min"`

Answer (score 0):

With your data in **A1,** in another cell enter:

```
=HOUR(A1) & "hr" & MINUTE(A1) & "min"
```